# Can Will save modifier from Elan "Resistance" stack with Will save modifier from "Empty Mind" psionic talent?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, psionics, stacking

Can an [Elan](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/psionic/monsters/elan.htm) use their Resistance (su) and [Empty Mind](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/alternative-rule-systems/psionics-unleashed/psionic-powers/e/empty-mind/) in the same round to gain a total of +6 on a Will save?

Comment: I have put some edits to improve your post's readability. If you disagree with any of my edits, you can always remove them in the editing history. Click the "edited X time ago" link to see all the previous revisions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## This could not normally be done in a single turn

### Both of these abilities use an Immediate action

> [*Resistance (Su)*](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/psionic/monsters/elan.htm):
> As an **immediate action**, an elan can spent 1 power point to gain a +4 racial bonus on saving throws until the beginning of his next turn.

Emphasis mine.

Manifesting [*Empty Mind*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/alternative-rule-systems/psionics-unleashed/psionic-powers/e/empty-mind/) also takes **1 immediate action**.

### When an Immediate action is used on your turn, it takes your Swift action as well

[Using an immediate action on your turn is the same as using a swift action and counts as your swift action for that turn.](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/Gamemastering/combat/#TOC-Immediate-Actions). Since a turn only has one Swift action, this makes the combination impossible.

## However, there are some ways to work around this

### [Corset of Delicate Moves](https://aonprd.com/MagicWondrousDisplay.aspx?FinalName=Corset%20of%20Delicate%20Moves)

"Once per day as a move action, the wearer can take an additional swift action. This swift action can’t be used to cast a spell or spell-like ability."

Since *Resistance* is a Supernatural ability (Su) and not a Spell-Like-Ability (Sp), it could be activated using the extra swift action.

*Empty Mind* is a typeless bonus, and *Resistance* is a racial bonus, so the +4 and +2 do stack.

### Use your next turn's Swift action

If you really need to benefit right away, you could spend your Swift action this turn to activate one of the abilities, and then, at the very start of the next person's turn, you could activate the other ability as an Immediate action. This will cost your next turn's Swift action, but it will give you the +6 before any attack affects you.

Comment: Hey, and welcome to RPG.SE! That's a very solid first post to write, and we hope that you have a very good time here. I have made some edits to your post; if you disagree with them, you can always revert them in the edit history (click on the "Edited X time ago" to see it).

Comment: Hi all!! Hi Baskakov_Dmitriy! Nice and functional site. I ve found all good answers, from good people.

Comment: -"This will cost your next turn's Swift action, but it will give you the +6 before any attack affects you."- But I can do this each round...so each round I gain +6 TS bonus, untill psionic points end right? Its not a "one more question", is a "deep explanation", isn't it?

Comment: You could effectively do this every other turn. Turn 1 you use your swift and then as soon as your turn ends use an immediate action to spend your next turn's swift action. Turn 2 you do not have a swift action to spend. As soon as turn 2 ends you could use an immediate action to activate 1 of the 2 abilities, but not both. If instead you don't use an immediate action after turn 2, then turn 3 has a swift action and could be the same as turn 1.